# WebDriverException (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, automation, webdriver

Ok, this was supposed to be a homework activity where I had to automate message forwarding on WhatsApp to at least 5 people. However, I'm getting the error WebDriverException. And I have no idea what that is .

Here the code:

Please don't mind the examples names

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import pyperclip

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
nav = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
nav.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
time.sleep(90)

mensagem = """Fala rebanho de fila da pota, isso aqui é um código automatizado, portanto desconsidere, é so um teste"""

lista_contatos = ['Salvos 2.0','B.D.Maltas', 'MALUQUICE 2.0', 'Mathews', 'Nataly❤', 'Adrian']

# enviar a mensagem para o Meu Numero para poder depois encaminhar

# clicar na lupa
nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="side"]/div[1]/div/div/button/div[2]/span').click()
nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="side"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys("Salvos 2.0")
nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="side"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)

# escrever a mensagem para nós mesmos
pyperclip.copy(mensagem)
nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")
nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)



# %%
# encaminhar a mensagem para a lista de contatos
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# %%
qtde_contatos = len(lista_contatos)

if qtde_contatos % 5 == 0:
    qtde_blocos = qtde_contatos / 5
else:
    qtde_blocos = int(qtde_contatos / 5) + 1

for i in range(qtde_blocos):
    # rodar o codigo de encaminhar
    i_inicial = i * 5
    i_final = (i + 1) * 5
    lista_enviar = lista_contatos[i_inicial:i_final]

    # selecionar a mensagem para enviar e abre a caixa de encaminhar
    lista_elementos = nav.find_elements('class name', '_2AOIt') 
    for item in lista_elementos:
        mensagem = mensagem.replace("\n", "")
        texto = item.text.replace("\n", "")
        if mensagem in texto:
            elemento = item
        
    ActionChains(nav).move_to_element(elemento).perform()
    elemento.find_element('class name', '_3u9t-').click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[4]/div/ul/div/li[4]/div').click()
    nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="main"]/span[2]/div/button[4]/span').click()
    time.sleep(1)

    for nome in lista_enviar:
        # selecionar os 5 conttos para enviar
        # escrever o nome do contato
        nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys(nome)
        time.sleep(1)
        # dar enter
        nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(1)
        # apagar o nome do contato
        nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
        time.sleep(1)

    nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/div/div/div/span').click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

It should work, but what I'm getting is:

**WebDriverException**

Error in

**---> 76** nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys(nome)

```
---> 76 nav.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p').send_keys(nome)

File c:\Users\victo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:231, in WebElement.send_keys(self, *value)
    228             remote_files.append(self._upload(file))
    229         value = "\n".join(remote_files)
--> 231 self._execute(
    232     Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {"text": "".join(keys_to_typing(value)), "value": keys_to_typing(value)}
    233 )

File c:\Users\victo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:395, in WebElement._execute(self, command, params)
    393     params = {}
    394 params["id"] = self._id
--> 395 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File c:\Users\victo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:345, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    343 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
...
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x767500C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779F7B1E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779F7AEE+238]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

Comment: if `it should work` you won't get an exception => `it does not work`